# How to deal with uncertain number of image data in UITableViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to build a `tableView` with dynamic content which is brought back from a web server. The data sent by the web server can be treated as an array. Each member of it contains some texts and may or may not contains some images. I want to use a `UITableViewCell` to represent one member of the array but can't figure out how to deal with the uncertain number of images. How can I deal with this kind of issue? Or are there some other kind of solution?

Thanks a lot.

## **EDIT 1**

It seems questions consist of only texts hardly get correct answer. So here is what the data sent by web server looks like:

```
{
"data": [
    { 
        "author":"Bill" , 
        "content":"apple is great" , 
        "replyTime":"2014-04-23 22:22:00" 
    },
    { 
        "author":"George" , 
        "content":"banana is great too, have a look at the picture[imgstart]http://img.example.net/banana.jpg[imgend]",
        "replyTime":"2014-04-23 22:25:00" 
    },
    { 
        "author":"Thomas" , 
        "content":"peach is better, see[imgstart]http://img.example.net/peach1.jpg;http://img.example.net/peach2.jpg[imgend]",
        "replyTime":"2014-04-23 22:25:30"
    }
]
```

}

**pay attention to the third JSON array member**, there are two image links between [imgstart] and [imgend] separated by semicolon which means there are two images in one reply.

My question was asking during designing the view of a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, how can i arrange the `imageView`?

sorry for the confusion

## EDIT 2

A suggestion from my friend is that I should use a webView to show the data in a web page.

Comment: As the web server sending the data in Array once downloaded use the array to load it into UITableView. You need to reload the tableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configure your cell you can check if there is image for certain indexPath and if it is, allocate new UIImageView, set image property and add in to the cell's content view. Otherwise just display text.

```
-(UITableViewCell)tableviewForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)index
{
   ...
   if([data[index.row] hasImage])
   {
      UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
      imageView.image = data[index.row].image;
      [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems like the closest answer. I'm not quite familiar with layout in code so may i ask you one more question that can this be done in storyboard or xib? if it can't and I allocate new imageView like you did where will the imageView appear, after the text content?

Comment: Where imageView will appear depends on what frame you specify for it. And yes, if I understand you. You can. In storyboard you can select dynamic prototype for tableView and create two different cell prototypes with different reusable identifiers, one with imageView and one without. In code when you call UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier]; you specify which one to use. Doing so you can setup frame for your imageView in IB, not in code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the number of items in your array to determine the numberOfRowsInSection - that will populate the UITableView with the correct number of cells.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put a `UIScrollView` to you `UITableViewCell`, if there are too much image to show, which width is larger than cell's width. Then images can scroll left to right.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to implement `UITableViewDataSource` protocol ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) in one of your objects (can be View Controller hosting your `UITableView`, for instance);

Second, you configure `UITableView` by setting its `dataSource` to the object implementing `UITableViewDataSource` protocol;

Lastly, whenever you receive new data, you call `reloadData` on your `UITableView`. This causes data to be reloaded and methods from `UITableViewDataSource` to be called again.

Answer (score 0):

First parse the JSON and have links and stuff easily available in the model class.

Subclass the UITableViewCell and populate it with e.g.

```
- (void) populateCellWithData: (YourModelClass *)data;
```

When populating the contents you add the images. If you need different layout for the different cases, you can do the layout in

```
- (void) layoutSubviews;
```

It will be called before the cell is shown and you can set the sizes and locations of the various subviews there.

Hope this helps.